# Automatically build UML class diagram for unmaged C++ code in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class-diagram

So, I tried Visio UML reverse engineering, but it worked about 20 minutes, put Visual Studio in non responding state and showed some warnings like `"Couldn't reverse engineer a namespace"`. So, is there a way to build class diagram in a reasonable time? Also, it would be nice to have an opportunity to manually exclude some sources from parsing (like extern source, SQLite, for example.

Comment: You only have to do it once, right?  Did you get a diagram at all, or did you get nothing?  Note that Visual Studio has it's own class diagram creator, and it's quite good.

Comment: Once in few weeks, I guess. Didn't get anything. Maybe I should wait more, but this tool wasn't showing any activity except for warnings.